# click is not working in selenium due to presence of tooltip in web browser. How to make click work or hide tooltips so that click will work

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am doing an automation project for my organisation. I am  using Firefox Web Browser for this purpose. Code is working fine but is stuck at one point in between the program.Problem is related to clicking on a webelement. `With selenium code 1.I have to first click on complete task  2. After clicking on complete task submit option appears on webpage and I have to click on submit button as shown in image`.[image: Here is image when I click on complete task]

As seen in this image when I click on complete task it is showing information about complete task element. Next I have to click on submit part but due to this tooltip program is unable to click on submit element. [image: Here is the image of submit]

Following is the Html of `Complete task` element

```
<img class="completeTask" src="pics/transparent.gif" name="WFCompleteTask" onmouseout="tryHideCompleteTask()" onmousedown="MM_swapImage('WFCompleteTask','completeTaskOnClick','pics/transparent.gif',1);showCompleteTask(this);" alt="This will save and submit your order and complete your task. You may not edit this task after you have completed it." title="">
```

Following is the html of submit element

```
<td class="completeTaskDropdown"><nobr>submit</nobr></td>
<nobr>submit</nobr>
```

While debugging the program , program shows it has clicked on complete task and submit button but actually in web browser it has not clicked none of these.I have tried all the possible ways to solve this problem but unable to get proper answer.
Following is the a short code snippet for the above task

```
firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference("plugin.state.flash", 2)
firefoxProfile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile, executable_path=r'drivers\geckodriver.exe')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
complete_task = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@name='WFCompleteTask']")))
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", complete_task)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", complete_task)
submit = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//nobr[contains(text(),'submit')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)
```

I have also tried Actionchains and manual click also-

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(submit).click(submit).perform()
```

Also tried

```
complete_task.click()
submit.click()
```

But unfortunately no method works for clicking on complete_task and after that submit button. In stack overflow I found some jquery code but that also not works for hiding or removing tooltips. Following is that code

```
driver.execute_script("""
                    unction hideTips(event) {  
    var saveAlt = $(this).attr('alt');
    var saveTitle = $(this).attr('title');
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).attr('title','');
        $(this).attr('alt','');
    } else {
        if (event.type == 'mouseleave'){
            $(this).attr('alt',saveAlt);
            $(this).attr('title',saveTitle);
        }
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a").live("hover", hideTips);
});      """)
```

But above code is not working. Tried my code in Internet Explorer browser also but same problem arises in internet explorer also. How to hide these tooltips from webpage or if hiding tooltips are not possible than how to get click on both complete task and submit button with the help of automation script.

Note: Previous week this project and click was working fine but due to change in code with ui(addition of tooltips in webpage by team of this tool) this click is not performed

Comment: I would have thought selenium doesn't directly falsify the click, but rather interacts with the element. I may be wrong. What happens if you execute the following script to remove the 'alt' attribute? "document.querySelector('.completeTask').removeAttribute('alt')"

Comment: @Sri driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.completeTask').removeAttribute('alt')") is giving exception selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: JavaScript error

Answer (score 3):

I have been troubleshooting a similar issue recently. The hover tooltips text does not disappear after click on the first element, thus failing the subsequent click on another element (as the element is blocked by the tooltips, similar to your case). This issue only happens on Firefox but not Chrome.

I haven't figured out why the hover tooltips text remains on UI after the click. The workaround I found is to use Actions class's click instead of Webdriver's click() for the first element, which will not show the hover tooltips and therefore not blocking the second click.

Comment: Thank you. But this tool is not supported in Chrome web Browser that's why I am using firefox and I am struggling with this web element from past four days. Have you aware of any other solution?

Comment: no method is working. Based upon this html can you give some other clue

Comment: The workaround I mentioned is for Firefox.

To clarify, for my case, the problem happened due to the click on a web element with a tooltips text. That, in you case, could be the 'complete task' button.


Did you try to use Actions click for that? 

`ActionChains(driver).click(complete_task).perform()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
submit = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//nobr[contains(.,'submit')]")))
ActionChains(drivers).move_to_element(submit).click().perform()
```

or

```
submit = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//nobr[contains(.,'submit')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thank you for response. But I have already mentioned in the question that I have tried all the above possible ways before posting this question , you can check I have used actionchains and execute script

Comment: Can you post your url?

Comment: it is url of organisation which only works on organisation's intranet

Comment: What exception are you getting? Have you verified your element is not in the iframe

Comment: I have verified that element is not in iframe. I do not get any exception. But while debugging program executes these click lines successfully but after clicking another window handle appears. So this click not work, hence window handle not appears and program gives list index out of range when i tried to switch on another window handle

Comment: it is not giving exception on clicking line in the code but also not clicking on the web page

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```
javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].submit()", webElement);
```

or try send keys event.

Comment: Thank you.But in python javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].submit()", webElement); is not used for javascript rather I have already mentioned before asking my question that I have used driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit) but it has not worked